# Editing Started and Editing Completed event for Textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, textbox

In WPF textbox, is it possible to get Editing Started and Editing Completed event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this link and see if it helps.

[TextBox.TextChanged & ICommandSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855/textbox-textchanged-icommandsource)

The basics here are through binding yes.  1 way is to bind to an objects property which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  You are actually responding to the property changing rather than the text box.

Comment: Look into two way binding. That's really where you will see the benefit of this.

Answer (score 1):

the best you are going to have is `LostFocus` and `GotFocus` events.  You can also get as granular as mouse, keyboard, and/stylus lost/got focus events.  Also, you can check out the `PreviewTextInput`  event

here are the MSDN docs:

[LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[GoFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)